# partitions question

Tags: combinatorics

Show that the number of partitions of a set of size $n$ into two non-empty parts is $2^{n-1}-1$.

So let $A=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to do this please.

EDIT: Are we basically trying to find $\{{n\choose 2\ }\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B$ be a subset. Then $B$ and $A\setminus B$ is a partition of $A$. We require partitions to be non-empty, so $B\not = \emptyset, A$. Thus, the choices for $B$ consist of all non-trivial subsets of $B$. There are a total of, 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n\choose k} = 2^{n} - 2$$
Such subsets.

But since we regard $\{ B,A\setminus B\} = \{A\setminus B,B\}$ to be the same, we divide that overall number by $2$.